# How to access variables from iOS static library in client application?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am builiding libraries in iOS, for that i want to access variables from my iOS static library. To do this, is it necessary to declare variables used in my library class as public variables?, so that I can access variables from my library class from another application?

If so, how to declare variables as public in library class? If not, is there any other method to access variables from library in client application?

Answer (score 0):

If the headers are copied in the Copy Files build phase, then their symbols will be available to the client application which links your static library.  This build phase is created automatically for you when Xcode creates the static iOS library project.

If you wish to exercise more control over which headers are public and which are private, then you'll need to create separate copy headers build phases for public and private headers and manually move header files between those build phases.  You'll also need to adjust the header search paths.  [This blog post](http://rheard.com/blog/creating-static-ios-libraries/) may help with those implementation details.